# Is there a way to use * inside of querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html

I have such selectors:

```
i = 0; i < 24
```

`ctl03_ctl00_G0_G1_0_0_0_G22_2_0_0_G23_3_GetShiftInput_ShiftButton_496_0_Editor_${i}`

As far I know I can substitute these 'random' sequence of letter and digit like this:

`document.querySelector('[id*="_ShiftButton_496_0_Editor_${i}"]').innerText`

Is they a way to refer to that selector:

`document.querySelector('[id*="_ShiftButton *_Editor_${i}"]').innerText`

by accessing the selector that has these words and whatever is inside of it.
Point is to loop over each element and access it's text.

By far I am using:

`document.querySelector('[id*="*_Editor_${i}"]').innerText`

However, it feels very imprecise.

Comment: `*=` is valid to specify that you want a "contains" search of the attribute value, but you cannot use `*` as a wildcard within the search string.

Comment: Does the `_0_` change?  I guess I'm not sure why you need this.  Also given the use case I would think an ends with `$=` would be more appropriate

Comment: Post an example html structure

Comment: You can query all elements that have `ShiftButton` in their ID, then filter them using plain JavaScript

Comment: I need this, because these random digits and letters change depending on settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute selectors do not support wildcards, but you can combine substring matching attribute selectors.

```
[id*="_ShiftButton"][id*="_Editor_"]
```

For an attribute which contains both substrings.